# How do I mount a remote folder on a Mac Pro server upon boot without having the user log on?

Tags: macos, launchd, sshfs

I need to mount a remote folder upon boot without having the user log on.

I am able to mount the folder via terminal while logged on on the server but the folder doesn't mount when launchd is triggered.

The remote folder is accessed via SFTP using an SSH key.

While logged on as the user this is the command I'm using in terminal to mount the volume:

`sshfs -o allow_other,IdentityFile=/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa remoteuser@remoteserver: /Users/username/localpath -p 22 -o workaround=nodelay -ovolname='remoteuser@remoteserver' -C /tmp/sshfs-tmp.err`

After running this, the volume is mounted and can be used.

I can also run `sftp -i /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa remoteuser@remoteserver` successfully

With this command tested, I used Michael Ramsey's [script](https://whattheserver.com/keep-your-sshfs-mounts-mounted/) to run this via launchd

The script is located in `/Users/username/.scripts/mount_sftp.sh`

Then I created this plist file:  `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.testing.mountSftp.plist`

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "~//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
        <dict>
                <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
                <dict>
                        <key>PATH</key>
                        <string>/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:</string>
                </dict>
                <key>Label</key>
                <string>com.testing.mountSftp</string>
                <key>RunAtLoad</key>
                <true/>
                <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>
                <true/>
                <key>UserName</key>
                <string>username</string>
                <key>Program</key>
                <string>/Users/username/.scripts/mount_sftp.sh</string>
                <key>StandardOutPath</key>
                <string>/Users/username/sftpmountjob.log</string>
                <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
                <string>/Users/username/sftpmountjob.log</string>
                <key>KeepAlive</key>
                <false/>
                <key>Debug</key>
                <true/>
        </dict>
</plist>
```

After restarting the server, this shows up in `/tmp/sshfs-tmp.err`:

```
$ cat /tmp/sshfs-tmp.err
remote host has disconnected
```

I appears as if the remote server is missing some user context when the script runs at boot and refuses the connection.

What can I change in my script or on the remote server to allow this connection to happen when ran by launchd?

(Full disclosure: I am not a Mac/Linux expert by any means)